# How to programatically download all files from a directory listing-enabled IIS server?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-8, iis-10, iis-8.5

I setup an IIS server to transfer files, I enabled directory listing, and when I click on the individual files, the download starts, but I don't want to have click through every single file.

Is there a program that can download all files from an IIS directory listing enabled site?

I tried using tools like Free Download Manager, but you still need to specify the link to each file you want to download. It didn't meet my needs as I already enabled directory listing because I want to download every single file.

Comment: You can try to use `directoryBrowseSection[""] = @"None"` to get the file name or directory name returned in the directory list, and then download according to these file names. [Sample Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse#c).

Comment: @samwu directory listing is already enabled and is returned but what program can i use to auto click on all the files in the directory for auto downloading

Comment: What code do you want to use? You can try to traverse all the files, and then download according to the file name.